# Links don't work on the production server after moving from the development server

Tags: caching, .htaccess

I have moved my Drupal site from localhost to live server but all links and contents are not access able and it gives:

> 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

I have tried:

- clearing all caches, session and watchdog tables
- replacing all localhost links on the exported sql file with live site name
- changing database connection info on setting.php file

Still I have no luck.

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers :) Please refrain from adding things like _this is a matter of life and death_ to the post, as they don't relate to the actual question. Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like missing .htaccess file. Check if this file exists or not. If not, upload a standard drupal htaccess file.

You can use this one maybe. https://github.com/drupal/drupal/blob/7.x/.htaccess